# How make toolbars moveable in e4 application

Tags: toolbar, e4

How can I make toolbars moveable in e4 application?
I've added DnDAddon to my application model but it doesn't work for toolbars.

Edit: my problem was missing org.eclipse.ui.themes plugin in my product configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Add the tag 'Draggable' to the toolbar in the Application.e4xmi.

Looking at the `IBFDragAgent` class which deals with tool bar drag, it requires that the trim be an instance of `ImageBasedFrame`, this is created by the CSS code as long as the trim bar has at least one of the `frame-image` and `handle-image` CSS properties set.

Something like:

```css
.MToolControl.TrimStack 
{
    frame-image: url(./winXPTSFrame.png);
    handle-image: url(./winXPHandle.png);
    frame-cuts: 5px 1px 5px 16px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this doesn't work for me.
Here is my app screenshot and application model.  
![Application model](http://i57.tinypic.com/mtnvw6.png)
![Main window](http://i57.tinypic.com/xdtits.png)
I tried to set "Draggable" for toolbar element in top trimbar, but without success.
I also tried to set trimstack tool control for left trimbar with tags TrimStack and Draggable, but it isn't used at all, because in runtime there is ne trimstack tool control createf when minimizing left part (its id has perspective id in brackets).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

- I add to my ToolBar in the Application model file the Draggable tag.
- I add in the css file the following:

  ToolBar.Draggable { 
      /*frame-image: url(./winXPTSFrame.png); */
      handle-image: url(./winClassicHandle.png);
      frame-cuts: 5px 1px 5px 16px;
      color:  #ededed;
  }
- I add in my dependencies in the plugin.xml the following package: org.eclipse.platform (when the images are found)
  With this the draggable icon appears, you can go to org.eclipse.platform.images and see what Image feets your application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to edit your answer to make it more readable but I can't :(